# Why was my technical question about a Microsoft API marked as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I've asked a question regarding a Microsoft authentication flow. There're many other questions about Microsoft Graph API and [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) that aren't marked as off-topic and closed.

Question: [Is there any way to know if a user gave consent on behalf of an organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77766725/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-a-user-gave-consent-on-behalf-of-an-organization)

It might be because of "Questions asking for customer support with third-party services".
With possible solution "Instead, please direct your questions to the relevant company/organisation's technical support team". But if we take the [Google Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Calendar) API as an example, we can see that Google refers to Stack Overflow as a place to get help.

[Google Calendar API Support](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/support)

> Questions & advice
>
> We use the popular programming Q&A website Stack Overflow to field technical questions.
> Google doesn't own or manage this site, but you can sign in with your Google account.
>
> Stack Overflow contains questions on a variety of topics, and
> developers use the tag [google-calendar-api] to mark questions
> relevant to this service. You might want to add additional tags to
> your question to attract the attention of experts in related
> technologies.

So it leaves me confused as for when Stack Overflow is the place to make a question about some company's API and when it's not. I would be glad to get clarification on it.

Comment: Graph API? Isn't that [Facebook's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Microsoft has their own service called Graph API. IIRC it's for managing users for Azure AD.

Comment: There are several Google employees who monitor the relevant tags on Stack Overflow, hence the support recommendation. What makes you think the same applies for Microsoft?

Comment: @Phil so there's an informal agreement that if there are a company has people tracking specific tags then it's allowed to create such questions? Shouldn't it be mentioned in rules then? Also curious if it applies to every company or only to big ones.

Comment: What I mean is that just because one company recommends asking on Stack Overflow doesn't mean you'll get the same level of service from other companies. I would also hazard a guess that if you asked a similarly vague / product-related question about the Google Calendar API, it too would be closed for the same reason

Comment: Perhaps this meta question would be clearer without the _"well Google said it was ok"_ part. I'd focus on what makes your particular question off-topic

Comment: @Phil, I disagree. As you can see, people are downvoting both of my questions, while Makyen states that the question appears to be on-topic. It seems that we're not on the same page. As a Stack Overflow user who wants to follow the rules, I find the situation where my question is closed as off-topic, then reopened, but both of my questions are downvoted, quite uncomfortable. This is especially considering that I didn't break any rules and didn't receive any negative feedback.

Comment: Any downvotes you receive here don't really mean anything other than disagreement. Any acceleration in votes you receive on your main site question is probably (and unfortunately) due to the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/158281)

Answer (score 9):

Your question was closed as "Not about programming or software development" by three users with the privilege to cast close-votes. Why they cast the close-votes is something which only they could tell you. Other people could tell you why they think the question is off-topic and should be closed, but I can't do that, because it appears on-topic to me. As such, I've reopened it.

In my opinion, it's a specific question asking explicitly if some specific information is available either through the OAuth response or from the Microsoft Graph API. Now, it might be necessary for you to tell us in more detail which OAuth response you're talking about and/or which Microsoft Graph API you're asking about, but those descriptions seem sufficiently specific to me (e.g., you're not asking a resource request question asking for potential third party APIs).

Now, that doesn't mean I think it's a great question, or that it shows research effort. It just means that I think it's a specific programming question, as the information in the OAuth response and what data is available from the Microsoft Graph API are primarily questions relevant to a programming context.

##### As to what you quote from Google Calendar API Support

I'd be a lot more comfortable if what they said was only pointing *programming* questions to Stack Overflow, rather than "technical questions", as it's possible to have technical questions which aren't programming questions.

Comment: I'd say the question is still off-topic (too broad / needs more focus / details) so would have to disagree with re-opening it. There's been plenty of discussion about if the right close-vote reason was selected for closed questions; in the end does it really matter.

Comment: @Phil I'd like to see more in the question too. However, I suspect that if I was a subject mater expert (SME) in Microsoft's OAuth and/or the Microsoft Graph API, I'd be able to answer the question as currently written, particularly given the image of the UI that shows exactly which consent is being asked about. In other areas where I am an SME, what's provided would probably be enough, but could not be. If an SME wants to close it as "unclear", that's fine. I'm even happy to close it as "unclear" myself, if an SME explains why the information provided isn't sufficient to be able to answer.

Comment: @Phil Yes, on Stack Exchange sites, regular users don't, and shouldn't, reopen a question which they think should be closed for another reason. However, that's because of the amount of work and coordination between a significant number of users which the entire process requires. Moderators, on the other hand, are able to reopen and reclose for a different reason by themselves. As such, when we feel it's appropriate (e.g., reduces confusion, arguments, etc.) we will change the close reason. However, if I felt the question should be closed for another reason, I wouldn't have left it open.

Comment: So the first thing that happened after the question was reopened, was to place a bounty, so that SME wouldn’t vote to close the question.

Comment: @SecurityHound Yes, however, there's never been even a single comment or flag on the SO question, let alone one indicating additional information is needed. Also, there are no comments on this Q&A from anyone saying that there's any needed information missing from the question, any indication from anyone as to why it's actually closable, nor anyone claiming to be an SME saying that it's not answerable. If someone wants to actually indicate something other than a dislike for the question, then there's something to address, and, if closable, the bounty could be removed and the question closed.

Comment: I'm definitely willing to be shown that the question is off-topic and then remove the bounty and close the question, if that's shown to be the case. But it A) is about programming; B) doesn't appear too broad (a basic answer seems like it should be a couple/few paragraphs + some code, *way* below 30k characters); C) is focused and clear (and has been edited to improve that); and D) *appears* to have the minimum necessary details for an SME to answer (and more details have been edited into the question).

Comment: All of the above are rebuttable assertions. An SME might be able to easily indicate one or more are wrong and the question should be closed. But, nobody's even *tried* to do so.

Comment: It got a very nice answer from an SME. The question was edited a little bit, but I can't really imagine that the edit made much of a difference on how answerable it was by someone that knows their stuff. Maybe we should add a skip link next to the close/delete/flag ones. Don't know what it'll do, but people need to be able to click it.